# Search of object indexes

Tags: javascript

I trying to get indexes of all the

```
<div>
```

tags. This is how I am trying to do it. How can I correct this to show me all the matching indexes?

```
    allNodes = [];
    nodeList=document.querySelectorAll("*");
    for(var i = 0, n; n = nodeList[i]; ++i) allNodes.push(n);

    function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
        var indexes = [], i;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i] === val)
                indexes.push(i);
        return indexes;
    }

    testing = getAllIndexes(allNodes,"HTMLDivElement");
alert(testing);
```

Comment: What is this `"HTMLDivElement"` *string* supposed to do there?! And why are you comparing it to node objects?

Comment: Why not simply do `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` (or even use the `querySelectorAll` you already have)?

Comment: That's basically the question. What do I input instead of HTMLDivElement.

Comment: Nothing. There is no input `val` that does lead to the expected result. You will need to rewrite the `getAllIndexes` function.

Comment: Can you help me with a link or something. I can't seem to understand how or what I would need to do.

Comment: You need to change that `if (arr[i] === val)` line to something more suitable. Checking for [`.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) would be fitting, for example.